# remove the duplicate entry for the value in laravel view file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the response from the data as $am_details and I want to get the unique geo value in sect box dropdown  in view files
I have tries as

```
<select name="geo" class="ui fluid dropdown" id="geo" multiple="" >
    @foreach($am_details as $summary)
        <option value="{{$summary->Geography}}">{{$summary->Geography}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

But displaying with duplicate geo value I want to remove the duplicate entry in laravel view selectbx option.

`$am_details` response in as below

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [AccountManager] => jigar.lohia  [CustomerCode] => UAE_0068 [Geography] => ME  )
 [1] => stdClass Object ( [AccountManager] => jigar.lohia  [CustomerCode] => UAE_0068 [Geography] => ME ) 
 [2] => stdClass Object ( [AccountManager] => jigar.lohia [CustomerCode] => UAE_0068 [Geography] => ME ) 
 )
```

Comment: Can you show me your controller code pls ?

Comment: please check my updated post

Answer (score 2):

> In controller

```
$unique = $am_detials->unique();
```

Then u give unique data. Check the documenting
https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-unique

Answer (score 2):

You should set your `geography` field as unique in your migration.

```
$table->string('geography')->unique();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `groupBy()` in your controller.
For example:

```
$am_details = Model::groupBy('geo')->get();
```

It will group all the duplicates

Comment: data is fetched by API.so I cant add any query function